# What is wrong with this simple SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I've got the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Child_Name LIKE '%' + Child_ID + '%'
```

SQL Server is reporting the following: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int.`

Child_ID is of int data type, but I cannot see what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought my question was straightforward, and gave all the information necessary for an answer. Infact, the correct answer was shown in a matter of seconds/minutes. An explanation would be lovely.

Comment: surely you either want to compare the ID column of Children to Child_ID or a string value to the Child_Name?

Comment: @Tanner - This was for simple experimental purposes, no practical reasons at all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert `Child_ID` to a text type, otherwise it will implicitly convert '%' to a numeric (from its character code), hence the error you're getting.

Like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Children WHERE Child_Name LIKE '%' + CAST( Child_ID AS varchar(10) ) + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate / add an int to a varchar, this is an invalid operation. 
Try
`select * from children where child_name like '%'+cast(child_id as varchar(50))+'%'`